# How can I run test before generate signed apk?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-testing

I consider that Android Studio will run test before generate signed apk.

But AS didn't do that for me.It's not nice before package my apk, I need run the tests myself.

I'm not sure if **dependsOn** or other way can help me.I'm not sure weather my build.gradle has mistakes.

Some relevant code in gradle maybe like this：

```
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.xx.xx"
    versionCode getDefaultVersionCode()
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 19
}
dependencies {
    testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:3.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

I didn't write **testOption**.

My directory is like this(content before them is package name):

[image]

Answer (score 9):

To run all available tests, when building a release, make the task, that builds the release (e.g. `assembleRelease`) depend on the test tasks:

```
android {
    // ...
}
afterEvaluate {
    assembleRelease.dependsOn testReleaseUnitTest, connectedAndroidTest
}
```

The `afterEvaluate` closure is executed after evaluation (when the android tasks have been created). At this time the android tasks can be referenced as variable.

Instead of `testReleaseUnitTest` you can just use `test`, which runs unit tests for all variants.

Keep in mind that there are by default no instrumentation tests for the  `release` version of your app (build with `assembleRelease`). So in the above example, `connectedAndroidTest` runs the instrumentation tests for the `debug` version only.

Comment: The name "test "is always "test" or it's named by me? **assembleRelease.dependsOn** **test**  has run but **generate signed  apk** didn't stop?

Comment: Hmm,I found when I write like this **assembleFlavorRelease dependsOn test**, then it worked.I think every **assembleFlavorRelease** depending on the test is not a good idea.how should I do that?

Comment: Does this work? Couldn't make it. The tests do not run and build the AAB even with broken tests.

Comment: Thanks, Is it possible to run the test all before debug build also?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with Android development, but I think you could achieve your intent with adding this somewhere in your build.gradle:

```
sign.dependsOn test
```

Where *sign* is the signing of apk task (same name as from **gradle tasks**).